# Best way to initialize a constructor that does more than initialize

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

I'm new to c++, and I'm just looking for some insight into a question I have with c++ 11 constructors. I've heard that initializer list are the best way to initialize variables in a constructor. If you use and initializer list, you have to implement constructor only in header file. I don't know what the "industry standard" is on the topic, so I ask you.

Constructor 1 (Clouds.h)

```
   Clouds(float x, float y, sf::Texture texture, std::mt19937 randGen) 
                                : x(x), y(y), defaultX(x), defaultY(y) 
        {
            cloudSprite.setTexture(texture);
            cloudSprite.setPosition(x, y);
        };
```

Constructor 2 (Clouds.cpp)

```
    Clouds::Clouds(float x, float y, sf::Texture texture, std::mt19937 randGen)
{
    Clouds::x = x;
    Clouds::y = y;
    Clouds::cloudSprite.setTexture(texture);
    Clouds::cloudSprite.setPosition(x, y);
}
```

This situation may not matter, but there is a lot of old content, I know you have to be careful what you read, that doesn't apply anymore with c++ 11. Is this one of those instances?

This question came about because I had an implementation error when I ran this:

Clouds.h:

```
Clouds(float x, float y, sf::Texture texture, std::mt19937 randGen) 
                                    : x(x), y(y), defaultX(x), defaultY(y) {};
```

Clouds.cpp:

```
Clouds::Clouds(float x, float y, sf::Texture texture, std::mt19937 randGen)
    {
        Clouds::cloudSprite.setTexture(texture);
        Clouds::cloudSprite.setPosition(x, y);
    }
```

Comment: *If you use and initializer list, you have to implement constructor only in header file* that is not true. And yes, use an initializer list when possible. Second syntax is just confusing to read.

Comment: Well I have an "already implemented" error because in header file I had to use empty braces with initializer list.

Comment: I added the error that made me do some research. I found out that my problem was `{}` in header file, then using an non-empty constructor in cpp file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get that error because you have two definitions. If you want to write the definition in a source file ("out of line") then put the member initialisation list there too.

There is nothing about the member initialisation list that means you "have to" write your entire constructor definition in a header file.

You do need to put it wherever your *definition* goes, not where the *declaration* is.

```
Clouds(float x, float y, sf::Texture texture, std::mt19937 randGen);

// later...

Clouds::Clouds(float x, float y, sf::Texture texture, std::mt19937 randGen)
   : x(x), y(y), defaultX(x), defaultY(y)
{
    Clouds::cloudSprite.setTexture(texture);
    Clouds::cloudSprite.setPosition(x, y);
}
```

Comment: So if I use an initializer list, I also have to put it int the cpp file?

Comment: That definitely worked. Do you always use the initializer list in cpp file?

Comment: Your issue is not with initializer list. The issue is you only can have one definition. By trying to use it in header file you were making one definition (instead of usual declaration) and when it was later encountered in cpp it was considered duplicate definition.

Comment: I understand I believe. If i was only using the constructor to initialize then putting it only in header would be fine, but since thats not the case i initialize in cpp file.

Comment: @John: _"So if I use an initializer list, I also have to put it int the cpp file?"_ No. Put it wherever you like, as long as it's with the constructor's definition.